# Consume pipe one by one on event

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, rxjs5

lets imagine I have an array of items `A=[1,2,3,4,5]` and `Observable.from(A)`

I have a button, by pressing on which I want to pick 1 from my stream and put it on UI. So that A will look like `[2,3,4,5]`, then I click button again, and I pick one more item from pipe and bring it to UI. Repeat the above until pipe is empty, `A=[]`.

For event of button press I can use `Subject` and call `.next()` method. But how to pick items one by one from Rx stream?

Could you help me?

Comment: `Observable.zip(Observable.from(A), Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click'), a => a)`

Comment: Is the pipe of items (A) really a static list or does it need to be observable? If it is static then you can just do: `Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click').map(() => A.shift()).subscribe(x => { ... });`

Comment: In Angular, why would you use `fromEvent`? That seems to be missing the point.

Comment: @bygrace FromEvent will not help if I use radio button for example. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: @YauheniPozdnyakov Whether you use `fromEvent` or have an event binding callback feed a subject isn't the point of your question. I just put something there because I had to start the example with something representing a button click event.